# How to compare char option with char

Tags: ocaml

So as I understand a char option can be either None or any character such as 'a'.

How do I compare a char option to a regular char.

```
let first = Some 'a';;
let second = 'a';;
let third= 'b';;
```

How do I compare first and second so it returns true and first and third so it returns false.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case, you can do one of three things, depending on how you're using

```
let first = Some 'a'
let second = 'a'
let third = 'b'
```

First, you can turn the non-Option variables into Options and then test (structural) equality by doing:

```
if first = Some second then begin
  Printf.printf "First and Second are equal!"
end
```

Second, you can use a match statement. This is the more standard way to "unwrap" an Option:

```
match first with
| Some c -> 
  if c = second then print_endline "First and second are equal"; 
  if c = third then print_endline "First and third are equal."
| None -> print_endline "None."
```

Furthermore, you can wrap the match in a function as @ivg did in his example.

Lastly, you can use [`BatOption.get`](http://ocaml-batteries-team.github.io/batteries-included/hdoc/BatOption.html):

```
try
  if BatOption.get first = second then print_endline "First and second are equal";
  if BatOption.get first = third then print_endline "First and third are equal";
with
  No_value -> print_endline "ERROR: No value!!"
```

If you use `BatOption.get`, you'll want to wrap it in a `try/with` because if `first` is `None`, it will raise a `No_value` exception.

In general, though, the `match` is the most standard way to do it. As @ivg noted, using the match is marginally faster than constructing an Option object and running a comparison (especially when restricting the type and generating a function). If speed is not a great concern, then either will be fine. It's up to you and what seems most readable.

Also, as an unrelated side note/suggestion: don't use the double semicolon except after `main`, e.g.,

```
let main () = begin
...
end ;;
main () ;;
```

You only ever need those two double semicolons. This practice allows you to forget all of the weird double semicolon rules and have your programs "just work".

Comment: Your second solution is not correct: in the pattern-matching, `second` is used in pattern position as a catch-all variable, so that this branch will always be taken. I guess you'd want to write something like `match first with Some c -> if c = second then ... else if c = third then ... else ... | None -> ...`

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you to use the most clear solution:

```
first = Some second
```

although, one can say that this is not a very efficient way, since it performs an extra allocation. But you shouldn't be bothered with this, unless it is used in a very tight loop. If it is a tight loop, and you really pinpointed with a tracer, that you need to optimize it, then you can use

```
let option_contains opt (x : char) = match opt with
  | None -> false
  | Some y -> x = y
```

Note, this function is specially constraint to accept only values of type `char`, that makes it very fast. But again, this is just a play in the optimization. In general just stick with a most readable solution, i.e., `first = Some second`.

Comment: Michael, you're totally confused, your example with unbound `y` is a total nonsense, it is better to remove it.

Comment: ivg, my mistake, thank you for pointing that out. I did confuse myself with that example. I've updated my answer removing my 2nd edit and removing my recommendation to avoid the `first = Some second`.